# Strange behavior when marking with decreasing positions on multipart path.

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I mark a path at positions that are decreasing and the path contains two or more `to` parts, only the last `to` is taken into account.

Here is an example :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (4,4);
  \draw[very thick, draw=red,
      decoration={markings,
      mark=at position .3 with {\arrow[green]{*}},
      mark=at position .9 with {\arrow[black]{*}},
      mark=at position .3 with {\arrow[blue]{*}}, % the bad positioned mark
    },postaction={decorate}]
    (0,1) to[out=30,in=270] (4,3) to[out =90, in =-30 ] (0,4);
  % orange mark using only the second 'to'
  \path[decoration={markings,
          mark=at position -1.46 with {\arrow[green,scale=.5]{*}},
        },postaction={decorate}]
    (4,3) to[out =90, in =-30 ] (0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**My questions is :** Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug. The problem is that one cannot use positions in decreasing order. Page 585 of the manual says (italics for emphasis are mine)

> It is possible to give the `mark` option several times, which causes
>   several markings to be applied. In this case, *however, it is
>   necessary that the positions on the path are in increasing order*.
>   That is, *it is not allowed (and will result in chaos) to have a
>   marking that lies earlier on the path to follow a marking that is
>   later on the path*.

Isn't this what is happening here? You are placing marks at positions `.3`, `.9` and then `.3`, so chaos results.